# How can I define a Prisma field in the database that is Json type but map it to a defined TypeGraphQL object?

Tags: json, types, prisma, typegraphql

I would like to create a field that is `Json?` type in my schema.prisma file, but I would like to map it to a TypeGraphQL `@ObjectType()` class. I do not want a table in the database for the object. I want to store it as json in the db, but I want to make sure it conforms to a type I have defined in my gql schema. Is this possible? I am **not** using the `typegraphql-prisma` package. Here's a reduced down example (the code may not be perfect here, as I wasn't able to copy/paste):

Just one table in schema.prisma. `comments` is type `Json`, rather than defining a one-to-many relationship to a `Comment` model/table.

schema.prisma

```
model Post {
  id       Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title    String
  content  String
  comments Json?
}
```

But in my TypeGraphQL types, I want to define the properties that make up a `Comment`. I don't want to define `comments` as `Prisma.JsonValue`. I want it to be a list like `Comment[]`.

types.ts

```
@ObjectType()
export class Comment {
  @Field()
  id!:  number;

  @Field()
  content!: string;
}


@ObjectType()
export class Post {
  @Field()
  id!:  number;

  @Field()
  title!: string;

  @Field()
  content!: string;

  @Field((type) => [Comment], { nullable: true })
  comments?: Comment[] | null;
}
```

When I try to query, I get different TypeScript errors depending on different things I try. It doesn't like that I'm using JSON for my Prisma model and an object for my type definition for `comments`. Is it possible to define my db and types in this way? What is the best way to "transform" between the object and the JSON? Thanks!

```
import { Post as PostDb } from '@prisma/client';
import { Post } from './types.ts';

@Resolver(Post)
export class PostResolver {
  @Query((returns) => Post, { nullable: true })
  async getPostByTitle(title: string): Promise<PostDb | null> {
    try {
      return prismaClient.post.findUnique({
        where: { title }
      });
    } catch(error) {
      throw new GetPostError(error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, as far as I know, you must use [**`class-transformer`**](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) to convert from plain `JSON` to an instance of a *type-graphql* `class`.

### `Comment` class

Add `Expose` decorator, enabling the use of `excludeExtraneousValues`: extraneous properties should be excluded from the value when converting a plain value to a class.

```
// ...
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';

@ObjectType()
export class Comment {
  @Field()
  @Expose()
  id!: number;

  @Field()
  @Expose()
  content!: string;
}
```

### `PostResolver` class

Whenever a `Prisma` Post class is found, map it to a `type-graphql` class instance, using the utility function `mapPost`.

Note that for each `JSON` Comment we convert it to an instance of a (type-graphql) `Comment` class using the function `plainToInstance` from `class-transformer` library.

```
// ...
import type { Prisma, Post as PrismaPost } from '@prisma/client';
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';

@Resolver(Post)
export class PostResolver {
  /**
   * Map an instance of a Prisma Post class to
   *  an instance of a type-graphql class.
   *
   * @param post - Prisma Post class instance
   * @returns type-graphql Post class instance
   */
  private mapPost(post: PrismaPost): Post {
    return {
      ...post,
      comments: post.comments
        ? (post.comments as Prisma.JsonArray).map((comment) =>
            plainToInstance(Comment, comment, { excludeExtraneousValues: true })
          )
        : null
    };
  }

  @Query(() => Post, { nullable: true })
  async getPostByTitle(title: string): Promise<Post | null> {
    try {
      const post = prismaClient.post.findUnique({
        where: { title }
      });

      // Return null if post not found
      if (!post) return null;

      // Found! Map from Prisma to type-graphql
      return this.mapPost(post);
    } catch(error) {
      throw new GetPostError(error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

### Example

Imagine you have saved your JSON `Comment`(s) as:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "content": "Hello"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "content": "World"
  }
]
```

Now you should be able to execute the following query:

```
getPostByTitle(title: "Hello World") {
  id,
  comments {
    content
  }
}
```

Obtaining the following result:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "getPostByTitle": {
      "id": 0,
      "comments": [
        {
          "content": "Hello"
        },
        {
          "content": "World"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```